# Bash loop a curl request, output to file and stop until empty response

Tags: bash, curl

So I have the following bash file and right now its looping a curl request based on the for loop.  However, i am tying to find out how to continue looping until the response is empty.

Unfortunately the API that I am calling is based on pages with a maximum responses of 500 results per page.   I am trying to pull the data since 2017 so its a lot of data.

I want to continue countering until the response is empty.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Basic while loop
counter=1
for ((i=1;i<=2;i++));
    do
        curl -o gettext.txt --request GET \
        --url "https://api.io/v1/candidates?page=${counter}&per_page=500" \
        --header 'Authorization: Basic aklsjdl;fakj;l;kasdflkaj'
    ((counter++))
    done

echo $counter
echo All done
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: As a side note, I'd always use the `-L` option with curl.

Comment: Why not output to a new file every turn, and then grep for some html or whatever in the outputfile, until the grep turns up empty?

Comment: @Roadowl the output is a json response so from there, I was going to convert the json to a csv or excel file.   I did a test run and there is about 140 pages with 500 records each, so i dont really want 140 seperate files.

Comment: Make it work first, then optimize for the things you care about (like number of temporary files) afterwards.

Comment: @thatotherguy make which part work? the bash command works as is now, however, i am trying to find a way to exit the loop when there is not response.

Comment: You got a suggestion for how to exit the loop, but you rejected it because of the number of temporary files involved. My suggestion is to implement the fix first, then worry about the number of temporary files after.

Comment: @thatotherguy there is some suggestions below that worked without needing to create tons of files, just fyi in case you need to use it.   The accepted answer worked for me but the second one was really useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `break` to end the loop at any point:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((counter=1; 1; counter++)); do
  curl -o gettext.txt --request GET \
    --url "https://api.io/v1/candidates?page=${counter}&per_page=500" \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic aklsjdl;fakj;l;kasdflkaj'
  if [ ! -s gettext.txt ]; then
    break;
  fi
  # do something with gettext.txt
  # as in your question, it will be overwritten in the next iteration
done
echo "$counter"
echo "All done"
```

Comment: thank you, will do overwrite the txt file each time or will it append?  if it ovewrites, how can I append to it on each iteration?

Comment: To append, use a second file where you concat everything together. Add `cat gettext.txt >> everything.txt` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in author's comment on his/her own post, the returned data is in json format. The author didn't ask how to append two json files, but it is a necessary step for him/her to accomplish his/her job. In order to append two json's, json1 and json2, maybe skipping json1 last byte `}` and json2 first byte `{`, and appending `,` between them would be enough. Here I am using `jq` to join two jsons as a more generic approach.

In the examples shown below, the `nextjsonchunk` file is the json file got at each request. If it has contents, it is appended to the `mainjsonfile` with `jq`. If it seems to be empty (inferred by its size) the loop breaks and the result is moved to the present folder and cleanup is made.

Using `curl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tempfolder=/dev/shm  # temporary memory parition, avaiable in ubuntu
emptyjsonize=10      # the minimum json file length, to be used as a threshold

for ((counter=1; 1; counter++))
do
  curl "https://api.io/v1/candidates?page=${counter}&per_page=500" \
    --header "Authorization: Basic aklsjdl;fakj;l;kasdflkaj" \
    --ouput $tempfolder/nextjsonchunk
  if [ $(wc -c <$tempfolder/nextjsonchunk) -le $emptyjsonize ]; then break; fi
  jq -s '.[0]*.[1]' $tempfolder/mainjsonfile $tempfolder/nextjsonchunk > $folder/mainjsonfile
done
rm $tempfolder/nextjsonchunk # cleaning up
mv $tempfolder/mainjsonfile ./jsonresultfile # end result
```

Alternativelly, using `wget`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tempfolder=/dev/shm  # temporary memory parition, avaiable in ubuntu
emptyjsonize=10      # the minimum json file length, to be used as a threshold

for ((counter=1; 1; counter++))
do
  wget "https://api.io/v1/candidates?page=${counter}&per_page=500" \
    --header="Authorization: Basic aklsjdl;fakj;l;kasdflkaj" \
    --ouput-document $tempfolder/nextjsonchunk
  if [ $(wc -c <$tempfolder/nextjsonchunk) -le $emptyjsonize ]; then break; fi
  jq -s '.[0]*.[1]' $tempfolder/mainjsonfile $tempfolder/nextjsonchunk > $folder/mainjsonfile
done
rm $tempfolder/nextjsonchunk # cleaning up
mv $tempfolder/mainjsonfile ./jsonresultfile # end result
```

- It is a good idea to take two sample json and test the merging between them, to check if it is being done properly.
- It is also good to assure if the empty json file check is ok. The 10 byte was just a guess.
- A `tmpfs` (in memory) partition, `/dev/shm` was used in the examples, to avoid a many writes, but its use is optional.

Comment: do you know How this work on a mac where that type of partition does not exist?

Comment: I have never worked with mac, maybe someone knows and can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Basic while loop
counter=1
while true; do
    data=$(curl --request GET \
        --url "https://api.io/v1/candidates?page=${counter}&per_page=500" \
        --header 'Authorization: Basic aklsjdl;fakj;l;kasdflkaj')
    [[    $data ]] || break
    echo "$data"   >> gettext.txt
    ((counter++))
done

echo $counter
echo All done
```